# Board files for MYiR Z turn lite FPGA dev board

Tags: fpga, development-tools, toolchain

I have searched extensively but wasn't able to find the board files for a chinese dev board MYiR Z Turn lite. The vendor website doesn't seem to have it and I'm not able to wrap my head around the fact that this product does not come with board files needed to burn the bitstream in Vivado. Can anyone help me how to go about obtaining board files for a specific dev board? I have written to the vendor but no response.

Comment: contact the manufacturer ... in the future, do not buy a paper weight

Comment: I appologize, just frustrated that my project got stuck due to this. I'm trying to contact the vendor, but to no avail. I was hoping to get clues on a website or repository that will solve my troubles :)

Comment: @jsotola, if by a 'paperweight', you're meaning that it must be a cheap board from an obscure manufacturer hence bad support, this is far from that. Xilinx list this board on their website and endorse the manufacturer as a Xilinx partner (see https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-pcz4jb.html). So the OP has chosen a credible supplier that they would reasonably expect good support from. There's not need to change that approach in the future, anyone would presume the same as the OP.

Comment: @TonyM "paperweight" is functionaly synonymous with "bricked" ... it does not refer to quality or cost

Comment: @jsotola, doesn't affect my comment then, which is valid either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board is listed on the Xilinx ['boards and development kits'](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-pcz4jb.html) page for this FPGA and the manufacturer is endorsed as a Xilinx partner.

As Xilinx are recommending this board and manufacturer, use the Xilinx website Support to raise a help request and pursue it through them.

Comment: I hadn't thought xilinx would have any responsibility, but as you said, they may be helpful and I have raised a query. Thanks! Will update if I hear back. :)